Trying to install JavaFX in VS Code
This is the error I get when I try to create JavaFX project. First I was facing problem with JAVA_HOME (which I fixed). Now this:
Executing task: ""c:\Users\User-name\.vscode\extensions\vscjava.vscode-maven-0.44.0\resources\maven-wrapper\mvnw.cmd" org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-archetype-plugin:3.1.2:generate -DarchetypeArtifactId="javafx-archetype-fxml" -DarchetypeGroupId="org.openjfx" -DarchetypeVersion="RELEASE" -DgroupId="com.example" -DartifactId="demo" -DoutputDirectory="c:\Users\User-name\Desktop\JavaProject"" 

Exception in thread "main" java.util.zip.ZipException: zip END header not found
        at java.base/java.util.zip.ZipFile$Source.findEND(ZipFile.java:1649)
        at java.base/java.util.zip.ZipFile$Source.initCEN(ZipFile.java:1657)
        at java.base/java.util.zip.ZipFile$Source.<init>(ZipFile.java:1495)
        at java.base/java.util.zip.ZipFile$Source.get(ZipFile.java:1458)
        at java.base/java.util.zip.ZipFile$CleanableResource.<init>(ZipFile.java:724)
        at java.base/java.util.zip.ZipFile.<init>(ZipFile.java:251)
        at java.base/java.util.zip.ZipFile.<init>(ZipFile.java:180)
        at java.base/java.util.zip.ZipFile.<init>(ZipFile.java:194)
        at org.apache.maven.wrapper.Installer.unzip(Installer.java:169)
        at org.apache.maven.wrapper.Installer.createDist(Installer.java:86)
        at org.apache.maven.wrapper.WrapperExecutor.execute(WrapperExecutor.java:121)
        at org.apache.maven.wrapper.MavenWrapperMain.main(MavenWrapperMain.java:61)


Tips: (A) For installing Java easily, SDKMAN!. (B) For VS Code, use the Oracle extension: Introducing the Oracle Java Platform Extension for Visual Studio Code. (C) You may find it easier to install a JDK that comes bundled with the JavaFX (OpenJFX) libraries. At least two vendors offer editions of their JDK products in that fashion: Azul Systems and BellSoft.

Did you follow the guide?

Edited tags to remove spring and swing tags, as you aren't using those technologies.

If you are having difficult getting the openjfx maven archetypes to work, you could checkout the openjfx vscode modular maven project example from git directly and start with that rather than a project generated from an archetype.

This command-line example may be useful for reference.
